Routing is failing using useParams
I am working on a small car e-shop project. I am trying to get the ProductDetails rendering in a new page when the user clicks on "more details" in Products, however, it is failing. First it is not showing the path at the browser bar which should be "http://localhost:3000/product-details" and second it is rendering the Home page.
App.js
import React from 'react';
import Cart from './pages/Cart';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import ProductDetails from './pages/ProductDetails';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() { 
 return (
   <Router>
     <Routes>
       <Route>
         <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
         <Route path="/cart" element={<Cart />} />
         <Route path="/product-details/:id" element={<ProductDetails />} />
         <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to ="/home" replace />} />
       </Route>
     </Routes>
   </Router>
 );
}

export default App;

Products.js
import React from 'react';
import toyota from '../assets/images/toyota_camry2023.png'
import honda from '../assets/images/honda_civic2023.png';
import ford from '../assets/images/ford_mustang2023.png';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function Products() {
  const cars = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Toyota Camry', price: 25000, img: toyota },
    { id: 2, name: 'Honda Civic', price: 27000, img: honda },
    { id: 3, name: 'Ford Mustang', price: 35000, img: ford },
  ]

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Find The Best Deals</h2>
      <h2>Available Cars</h2>
      <ul>
        {cars.map(car => (
          <li key={car.id}>
            <img src={car.img} alt={car.name} />
            <h3>{car.name}</h3>
            <p>Price: ${car.price}</p>
            <Link to={`product-details/${car.id}`} target="_blank">More details</Link>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Products;

ProductDetails.js
import React from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function ProductDetails() {
  const { id }  = useParams();

  const Product = {
    1: {
      Engine: '2.5L Inline-4 Gas',
      Drivetrain: 'Front-Wheel Drive', 
      Transmission: '8-Speed       Automatic', 
      Warranty: '5 Years / 100000 km'
    },
    2: {
      Engine: 'Turbocharged DOHC 16-valve Inline-4', 
      Drivetrain: 'Front-Wheel-Drive,',    
      Transmission: 'Continuously Variable Automatic', 
      Warranty: '3 Years / 60000 km'
    },
    3: {
      Engine: 'Intercooled Turbo Premium Unleaded I-4', 
      Drivetrain: 'Rear Wheel Drive with limited-slip differential', 
      Transmission: '10-speed automatic transmission', 
      Warranty: '3 years / 60000 km'
    },

  };

 const ProductDetails = Product[id];

 return (
    <div>
      <h2>Car Details</h2>
      <p>{ProductDetails.Engine}</p>
      <p>{ProductDetails.Drivetrain}</p>
      <p>{ProductDetails.Transmission}</p>
      <p>{ProductDetails.Warranty}</p>
      <button>Add to Cart</button>
      <button>Book a Test Drive</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ProductDetails;

Would you be able to help me sort this issue out. I tried changing the routing, checked the syntax, followed my tutorials, all with no success.

I don't see any issue with the router, routes, and the ProductDetails component. Where is Products rendered? What is the URL path navigated to in the address bar? Can you [edit] to provide a complete [mcve] and any additional debugging details you may have tried?

Upon click on "More details" on Product.js, the url should change from http://localhost:3000/home to http://localhost:3000/product-details. May be I am missing a Route in App.js and I should nest the  route within a new Route called  for example.

Yes, but where is Products, the component, being rendered so the we can see where you are linking from. You just need to show us a complete [mcve] so we can see what your code is doing, and where and how it's doing it. When you click that link, what is the resultant URL? If you are able to click that link then it's obviously being rendered somewhere and should effect some navigation action.

Exactly so in order to simply the issue, Products.js is coded as a component to be rendered on the Home page, That's why I didn't prefer to add it to the routing list in App.js as it will stay by default as part of the home page whenever the user visit the website. When the user click on ''more details'' in Product.js, the user will be routed to localhost:3000/product-details where the user can see these details. However, when I click on ''more details'' it just took me back to localhost:3000/home. Something might be wrong with the Routing setup in App.js.

Issue
The Product component is rendered by the Home component rendered on route path "/home" and uses relative link target paths. Relative paths work relative to the current URL path. When the current URL path is "/home" and a link target is to={`product-details/${car.id}`}, then the resulting navigation action will be to "/home/product-details/someIdValue". Since there is no explicit route path that matches the URL path, the path="*" wildcard matcher/"catch all" route is rendered and the UI redirects to "/home".
Solution
Use absolute link target paths. The difference between relative and absolute routes paths is that absolute paths start from root, e.g. "/". In other words, add a leading "/" character to your link target path values.
Example:
to={`/product-details/${car.id}`}

Code:
const cars = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Toyota Camry', price: 25000, img: toyota },
  { id: 2, name: 'Honda Civic', price: 27000, img: honda },
  { id: 3, name: 'Ford Mustang', price: 35000, img: ford },
]

function Products() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Find The Best Deals</h2>
      <h2>Available Cars</h2>
      <ul>
        {cars.map(car => (
          <li key={car.id}>
            <img src={car.img} alt={car.name} />
            <h3>{car.name}</h3>
            <p>Price: ${car.price}</p>
            <Link to={`/product-details/${car.id}`}>
              More details
            </Link>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}


it is working properly now, thank you very much for your support
